# Converting MDX Query to Calculated Member

Tags: mdx

I'm trying to convert the following query into an MDX Calculated Member:

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[InComplete Records]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [DW DR Incomplete]
WHERE ([Dim Provider Records].[Complete Date Time].&[1899-12-30T00:00:00])
```

What I've tried so far hasn't worked, but admittedly I'm not too familiar with MDX or calculated members. Doing it as a subquery just gives me the error that subselects only support queries on the column axis.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Incomplete Records 2]
AS  
(SELECT 
[Measures].[InComplete Records] ON COLUMNS
FROM [DW DR Incomplete]), 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're requesting a single tuple so I would write something like :

```
... AS ( [Measures].[InComplete Records], [Dim Provider Records].[Complete Date Time].&[1899-12-30T00:00:00] )
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Sorry for the late reply. This worked great. Is there a way to get the opposite of this as well? So if I want everything a measure by everything BUT the one used above? I tried EXCEPT(), but it ends up returning a new column for every date/time.